# Temperature and light relationship

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, temperature, intensity

Is the absorptivity of light affected when the temperature of the solution it passes through changes?

For example consider a Beer Lambert experimental set up. If the temperature of the solution changes does the intensity of the emitted light change too?(Given that the incident light has not changed)

Comment: It depends on the material in the solution.  I'm sure you know of mood rings, or temperature sensitive materials that change their scatter/absorption profiles as they become warmer or cooler.  (In that case, the trick is that the scatter/absorption profile changes for some _wavelengths_ and not others, so we see a color change.) The main point is that some materials used in a solution may exhibit a different absorption behavior with a temperature change, and others may not.

Comment: Thank you for answering